# creating a new column in polars applying a function to a column

Tags: python, xml, apply, python-polars

I have the following code for manipulating a polars dataframe that does not work

```
import polars as pl

# create a sample dataframe
dfpl = pl.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': ['<p>some text</p><p>bla</p>', '<p>some text<p><p>foo</p>', '<p>some text<p>']
})

def func(mystring):
    return mystring*2

def func2(xml_string):
    root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
    text_list = []
    for elem in root.iter():
        text = elem.text.strip() if elem.text else ''
        text_list.append(text)
    return test_list

# create a sample series to add as a new column
dfpl=dfpl.with_columns([(pl.col("A").map(lambda x: func(x)).alias('new_col'))])
dfpl=dfpl.with_columns([(pl.col("B").map(lambda x: func2(x)).alias('new_col2'))])

print(dfpl)
```

The first line for adding a column works, i.e. adding new_col

but the second one does not work.

The error that I get is:
ComputeError: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Series'

Basically the use case that I have iss that a column contains XML string that I have to manipulate creating a XML object and extracting information.

How can I proceed?

Comment: You're trying to do row-based transformations which means you need [`.apply` instead of `.map`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/expressions/user-defined-functions/)

Comment: but why it works with the first one and not the second one?

Comment: And apply gives: ComputeError: ParseError: junk after document element: line 1, column 16

Comment: The first one is the same as doing `pl.col("A") * 2` - you're performing a "supported vectorized operation". The `ParseError` is not coming from `.apply` - it is coming from your XML parser as your example strings are not valid "XML".

Answer (score 2):

Your first example works because `*2` is vectorized.

For example if you do

```
func(pl.Series([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

then you get back a series of the original multiplied by 2.

Your `func2` isn't vectorized. To use `map` then your function needs to operate on the entire column and return something like a Series.

For instance:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
def func2_series(xml_strings):
    ret_List=[]
    for xml_string in xml_strings:
        root = ET.fromstring(xml_string, ET.XMLParser(recover=True))
        text_list = []
        for elem in root.iter():
            text = elem.text.strip() if elem.text else ''
            text_list.append(text)
        ret_List.append(text_list)
    return pl.Series(ret_List)
```

followed by

```
dfpl.with_columns(pl.col("B").map(func2_series).alias('new_col2'))
```

will work.

Alternatively if you have

```
def func2(xml_string):
    root = ET.fromstring(xml_string, ET.XMLParser(recover=True))
    text_list = []
    for elem in root.iter():
        text = elem.text.strip() if elem.text else ''
        text_list.append(text)
    return text_list
```

then you can use apply and polars will do the looping for you.

```
dfpl.with_columns(pl.col("B").apply(func2))
```

btw, you don't need to use a lambda if the function you're passing accepts the exact `x` that you have. In other words where you have `.map(lambda x: func2(x))` you can just do `.map(func2)`. The lambda comes into play if you need to transform the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, use `.apply` instead of `.map`. Also, if you want only list of strings I recommend to use `beautifulsoup`s method `.stripped_strings`:

```py
import polars as pl
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# create a sample dataframe
dfpl = pl.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': ['<p>some text</p><p>bla</p>', '<p>some text<p><p>foo</p>', '<p>some text<p>']
})

def func(mystring):
    return mystring*2

def func2(xml_string):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_string, 'html.parser')
    return list(soup.stripped_strings)

# create a sample series to add as a new column
dfpl=dfpl.with_columns([(pl.col("A").apply(lambda x: func(x)).alias('new_col'))])
dfpl=dfpl.with_columns([(pl.col("B").apply(lambda x: func2(x)).alias('new_col2'))])

print(dfpl)
```

Prints:

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬────────────────────────────┬─────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ A   ┆ B                          ┆ new_col ┆ new_col2             │
│ --- ┆ ---                        ┆ ---     ┆ ---                  │
│ i64 ┆ str                        ┆ i64     ┆ list[str]            │
╞═════╪════════════════════════════╪═════════╪══════════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ <p>some text</p><p>bla</p> ┆ 2       ┆ ["some text", "bla"] │
│ 2   ┆ <p>some text<p><p>foo</p>  ┆ 4       ┆ ["some text", "foo"] │
│ 3   ┆ <p>some text<p>            ┆ 6       ┆ ["some text"]        │
└─────┴────────────────────────────┴─────────┴──────────────────────┘
```

Comment: I like the bs4 suggestion, they didn't say what library's ET they were using and lxml was giving empty strings back but I figured that's a separate issue than what was asked.